# rasterVis::levelplot Title Height

Tags: r, levelplot, rastervis

How do I change the vertical space between the raster and the title in a levelplot in R? For example, for an extra 2 lines of space I have tried

```
r <- raster::raster( matrix(runif(9),3,3) )
rasterVis::levelplot(r, margin=FALSE, main=list('My plot',line=2) )
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple way is to add blank lines in the title

```
rasterVis::levelplot(r, margin=FALSE, main=list('My plot\n'))
```

[image]

Comment: This can add space, but is hard to subtract space. See my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

```
rasterVis::levelplot(r, margin=FALSE, main=list('My plot',y=grid::unit(-2, "mm")))
```